# Select from a Selected SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL table named "ORDERS" with two attributes, {orderNumber(primary key), and customerNumber}. When I use

```
SELECT Orders.CustomerID, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS numOfOrders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY numOfOrders DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I get the results "11 18". which correspond to CustomerID: 11 made 18 orders( in this case, the customer that made the most order).

How do I return just the CustomerID and not the numOfOrders?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `LIMIT` so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `COUNT()` in the `ORDER BY`.  I would do:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BobbyBob - If this answer help you then you need to mark it as answer by selecting the tick mark t the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the main query as subquery and then select only customer id from the table.

```
SELECT CustomerID from(SELECT Orders.CustomerID, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS numOfOrders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY numOfOrders DESC) a
LIMIT 1;
```